# Can I toggle sales tax exemptions in Exp:resso Store templates?

Tags: expresso-store

I'm working on a store that serves both consumers and wholesale retailers. The consumers pay sales tax, but the wholesalers don't. In my template, I can check for a Member Variable to see whether the customer should be tax-exempt. Then, can I somehow [via POST]:

- toggle {tax_exempt} on a per-item basis?
- override the Tax Rate on a per-order basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do this using an extension.

For example, you could use the [store_process_product_tax](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/developers/extension_hooks.html#store-process-product-tax) hook to check the member variables, and change the tax rate being applied to all products.

Likewise, you could use that hook or other cart hooks to override the tax_exempt status on a per-item basis once items are in the cart.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, Adrian. You know me... I LOVE writing Store extensions!  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply; this is exactly the same situation we find ourselves in. Only, there doesn't appear to be a store_process_product_tax hook page anywhere in the docs any more (link above is broken). It's possible that it moved because of the new 2.0 update but if so could you please re-post it? Thanks,
Nathan H.

Comment: I didn't find this anywhere on the new Expresso Store site but got a quick reply on twitter. Here's the link to the v1 docs: https://exp-resso.com/docs/v1/index.html